# Multiple words between curly brackets in PHP

Tags: php, regex, split

I have the following string:

```
$string = "Hello from {me} to {you}";
```

What i want is an array with the words between the curly brackets (without the curly brackets of course.

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(2) "me"
  [1]=>
  string(3) "you"
}
```

I tried the following pattern but it only shows one word (with the brackets) selected.

```
/\{([^}]+)\}/
```

or

```
/\{(\s*?.*?)*?\}/
```

I am new to regular expressions.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `preg_match_all`?

Comment: @Script47 yes i did, produced two arrays with a weird result. Not the result i wanted to..

Comment: This user [contribution note](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php#101259) returns `{` and `}` too :\

Comment: While [`preg_match_all()`](http://ee1.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) addresses your explicit question, I'll wager that [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://ee1.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) is what you actually need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `preg_match_all`.  In the code below, `$results` is what you're looking for:

```
$raw_string = "Hello from {me} to {you}";
$pattern = "/{(.*?)}/"; //will match everything in { }

if(preg_match_all($pattern,$raw_string,$matches)):
    $results = $matches[1];
else:
    //no matches
endif;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the third parameter in `preg_match_all` to get the matched values in an array.

```
<?php

$string = "Hello from {me} to {you}";

preg_match_all('/\{([^}]+)\}/', $string, $matches);

var_dump($matches);

?>
```

Which produces,

```
array(2) { [0]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(4) "{me}" [1]=> string(5) "{you}" } [1]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(2) "me" [1]=> string(3) "you" } }
```

To get the clean version,

```
echo $matches[1][yourKey];
```

**Reading Material**

[`preg_match_all();`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php)

Comment: @FirstOne haha, both *1 min ago*! It showed the show comment notification as I posted the answer.

Comment: @FirstOne yep, I included that below, just wanted to show the whole output for the OP's interest.

Answer (score 0):

$string = "Hello from {me} to {you}";

preg_match_all('/{([^}]+)}/', $string, $matches);

print_r($matches[count($matches)-1]);